# Como realizar y/o validar un bucle for único con NodeJS y JSON

Tags: json, array, nodejs, bucle-for

tengo las siguientes lineas de código en NodeJS...

```js
 for (let i = 0; i < res.body.results.map(e => e.events.length); i++) {
        

        if( ((res.body.results.map(e => e.events[i].type) == 'var1')) {

                publicar('xxxx'); 

        }else if( ((res.body.results.map(e => e.events[i].type) == 'var3')

  publicar('xxxx'); 
  
  
      }else if( ((res.body.results.map(e => e.events[i].type) == 'var4')

  publicar('xxxx'); 
  
      }else if( ((res.body.results.map(e => e.events[i].type) == 'var5')

  publicar('xxxx'); 
  
  }
}
```

Estoy tratando de iterar los indices de un array, el indice [0], es decir..
 `res.body.results.map(e => e.events[0].type` tiene una condición de que cierto `type` se cumpla, y que al cumplirse ejecute la función `publicar();` 
,se salga y pase al siguiente indice [1] y haga lo mismo (si se cumple la condición ejecutar la función `publicar()` y seguir con el otro indice [2])

La pregunta y lo que quiero hacer es.. como hago para validar que el indice recorrido y previamente publicado ya no se siga recorriendo y por ende ya no ejecute la función de `publicar()`

En otras palabras solo esta permitido ejecutar la función de `publicar()` una sola vez por cada indice que tenga..

Comment: pueden haber *type* duplicados en tu arreglo? o son *type* unicos

Comment: @Paulo Urbano Rivera el type es único e irrepetible

Answer (score 1):

Como me indicas que todos los valores son unicos, no necesitas realizar tantas validaciones, ya que al recorrer cada elemento de tu arreglo ningun valor se repetira.
Por lo que solo debes hacer algo asi

```js
    const data = [
      { name: 'uno', value: 1, type: 'var1' },
      { name: 'dos', value: 2, type: 'var2' },
      { name: 'tres', value: 3, type: 'var3' },
      { name: 'cuatro', value: 4, type: 'var4' }
    ]
      
    data.forEach(i => {
      console.log(`entre con valor ${i.type}`)
    })
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas :)